# I wish to seperate Appbar and Drawer into two components - Material UI

Tags: reactjs

I would like to seperate AppBar and Drawer into two different components. But because of open-drawer icon and state i couldn't do this. Can any one help me out?
This is sample layout from https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/ (Mini Variant drawer) 
The look and feel should not change!!

Tried to keep  and  in two different components but failed to do because of open drawer icon

class Header extends React.Component {
    state = {
        open: false,
    };

```
handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
};

handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
};

render() {
    const { classes, theme, userProfile } = this.props;

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <AppBar
            position="absolute"
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, this.state.open && classes.appBarShift)}>
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open}>
                <IconButton
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="Open drawer"
                    onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                    className={classNames(classes.menuButton, this.state.open && classes.hide)}>
                    <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.grow}>
                    Configuration Repository
                </Typography>
                <UserProfile userProfile={userProfile} />
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            classes={{
                paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !this.state.open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
            }}
            open={this.state.open}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar}>
                <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                    {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
                </IconButton>
            </div>
            <Divider />
               <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>
            <Divider />
            <List>{otherMailFolderListItems}</List>
        </Drawer>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one component consisting of AppBar with a DrawerWrapper as a component and pass drawerOpen state to that component as a prop -

```
<div>
  <AppBar>
    <IconButton
      onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
     >
     </IconButton>
  </AppBar>
  <DrawerWrapper drawerOpen={this.state.drawerOpen} />
</div>
```

with handleDrawerOpen changing the state as -

```
handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({
      drawerOpen: true
    })
  }
```

And in the DrawerWrapper component -

```
<Drawer open={this.props.drawerOpen} />
```

From your code -

AppBar component -

```
class AppBar extends Component {
    state = {
        open: false
    };

    handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    handleDrawerClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes, theme, userProfile } = this.props;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <AppBar
                    position="absolute"
                    className={classNames(classes.appBar, this.state.open && classes.appBarShift)}>
                    <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open}>
                        <IconButton
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="Open drawer"
                            onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                            className={classNames(classes.menuButton, this.state.open && classes.hide)}>
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.grow}>
                            Configuration Repository
                        </Typography>
                        <UserProfile userProfile={userProfile} />
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <DrawerWrapper open={this.state.open} classes={classes} theme={theme} handleDrawerClose={this.handleDrawerClose}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

DrawerWrapper component -

```
class DrawerWrapper extends Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, theme, open, handleDrawerClose } = this.props;

        return (
            <Drawer
                variant="permanent"
                classes={{
                    paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
                }}
                open={open}>
                <div className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
                <Divider />
                <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>
                <Divider />
                <List>{otherMailFolderListItems}</List>
            </Drawer>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do all the state statements should be in DrawerWrapper component? or AppBar component?

Comment: All states need not to be in any one of them. drawerWrapper could have all the states which is local to it and AppBar has its own similarly. Its just the opening and closing of the drawer which you want to control from the Appbar should be in Appbar and passed as prop to drawerWrapper.

Comment: i now have 3 components <AppBar><Drawer>and<DrawerWrapper>, but not working. May be i am wrong somewhere. Dont know :(

1st two blocks of code i've kept in <AppBar>
<Drawer> seperate
<DrawerWrapper> as you said in 3rd block

Comment: No, DrawerWrapper and Drawer are not separate. Its a wrapper around Drawer. you can have or not have it. Its like a div around Drawer. I was using the name just to be clear that the drawer is in another component called drawerWrapper :). May be I made it confusing. Just have two components. appbar and drawer.

Comment: Thankyou @Monika Mangal.
This is not done! 
In the code section i have pasted my live code. Can you make it to 2 independent components namely <AppBar> and <Drawer> ?

Comment: Sure, I can check

Comment: {this.handleDrawerClose} is not working :(
drawer is not closing up @Monika Mangal

Comment: handleDrawerClose need to passed as a prop as well from the Appbar component and then used in drawer. I think you should read more about how states and props work in react - https://hackernoon.com/understanding-state-and-props-in-react-94bc09232b9c . Please check the updated answer

Comment: Great, super that you got this working. Good luck with learning react :-)